# Match condition in each occurrence

Tags: java, regex

How can I do to match each occurrence of a regex in a String? For example, what I want to do is to match that each "<=" in a String has a number at the left and at the right of it (if "<=" is present).

What I have is something like this:

`\d+ (<=) \d+`

But the string "4 <= 3 && 1 <= f" is true because the first case is correct, and if the "<=" is not present returns false.

I'm going to implement this regex in Java.

Is there anyway to do this with regex?

Comment: Not every parsing problem can be solved with regular expressions. If you really want to be able to parse **any** kind of numerical expression like in your example ... then you need a real **parser** that does more than just simple regex matching.

Comment: So step no. 1: get really clear about your requirements.

Comment: With that regex the String "2 > 3" is false (is has to be true because "<=" is not present) and "3 <= 5 && gg <= 3" is true (is has to be false because the second case is incorrect).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. That why I'm asking, if there is anyway to do it with regex or if you know any Java parser that I can use for that.

Comment: The requirement is clear, if you don't understand something please ask me. I want to know if I can do that with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex:

```
String regexp = "((?<d>)\\d+|[^0-9])<=((?<d2>)\\d+|[^0-9])";
String text = "4<=3 && 1<=f";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regexp).matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
        boolean result = !(matcher.group("d") == null && matcher.group("d2") != null ||
                           matcher.group("d") != null && matcher.group("d2") == null);
        System.out.println(result);    
}
```

It prints:

```
true
false
```

P.S. Certainly a parser would be a better approach here.